# can I emit a sequence of signals in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I have this code:

```
if (condition) {
    emit signal1();
    emit signal2();
    emit signal3();
    emit signal4();
}
```

Would this work as well?:

```
if (condition)
    emit signal1(), signal2(), signal3(), signal4();
```

The code compiles but I am not sure if all signals are emitted

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. `emit` will be converted to nothing during preprocessing stage:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_EMIT
# define emit
#endif
```

For each signal Qt will generate public method, so you will get just a bunch of methods executed with comma.

Also you can just not write `emit` at all and it will work in a same way.